# Problem with Flutter Test Framework or VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, testing

When I run a test that fails, instead of Flutter Test Framework and VSCode highlighting this failed test, they highlight the top of my code. The first image shows the test failing on line 294, but the failure error highlights line 146. Does anyone know what can be and how to solve it?

[image: Test failing]

[image: Highlighted part]

Comment: not sure if related or not, but it's the only test-related issue ticket I could find: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4351. If it doesn't match your issue, I suggest you also raise an issue ticket there. If you do, please ping me here with a link to it.